# Filter different value in the same column

Tags: php, mysql

May I have any idea or suggestion on filtering the different value in the same column in MYSQL.

What I've tried as following,

```
SELECT * FROM (select  * FROM `testschema.pd` where status <> 2)  alldata where status =1 order by week desc
```

> [image]

As image, 
Value 1= Open, 2=Reject, 5=Close,
I would like to filter out those document which 1 (Open) that already been 2 (Rejected) and 5 (Closed) do not been showed.

Comment: Maybe `group by` the ID, then `group_concat` the 1-5 columns, then use `find_in_set` or a regex.

Comment: @user3783243 After I tried the one you suggested, is it possible minus or except those which are status=5 (closed), code as following, SELECT wo , group_concat(status)as 'statuss'
FROM `testschema.pd` 
where  find_in_set(status,'1,2,5')
group by wo

Comment: You need to `group_concat` the `status` otherwise you are only looking at one of the rows.  I think something like `find_in_set('1', group_concat(status)) or find_in_set('2', group_concat(status)) or find_in_set('3', group_concat(status))` might do it

Answer (score 0):

I assume id to status mapping is one to one.

You have following data,

```
Table : temp
id      status
181689  1
181689  5
181690  1
181690  5
181691  1
181691  2
```

To find records which are opened and closed, you can use,

```
select id from temp
where status in (1, 5)
group by id
having count(status) > 1
order by id;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to filter the data which has the status 1 (open) and 2 (Rejected).
From the SQL filter, you need to remove the status 5(closed).

For that, you can use the below query.

```
SELECT * FROM alldata
WHERE status IN ('1', '2');
```

This above query filters the data which has status 1 and 2.